# Decimal REM based font size not working as expected

Tags: css

ok, lets see if I can explain this.

If I set the body font-size to 16px, the below code works fine, but if I set body font-size to 100% it does not work. (even if 100% equals 16px)

Element "a" should have a font-size of the same as body, so most likely 16px.
Element "b" should have 10% font-size, and element "c" a 30% font size.

The issue is only with Chrome and Vivaldi, element "b" and "c" dont seem to want to go lower than 6px "via" REM, while Firefox and IE are happy to get them down to whatever 1 or 2 pixel it works out at, they both! end up the same size, 6px in the former.

I used Chrome addon CSSViewer for this...and my eyes :P

Is this a bug? or am I doing something wrong? I would really like to be able to get it to work in Chrome and Vivaldi as well...

Here is the example:

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}
#a {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
#b {
  font-size: 0.1rem;
}
#c {
  font-size: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  Hello world!
</div>
<div id="b">
  Hello world!
</div>
<div id="c">
  Hello world!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your browsers settings. In Firefox'  case, next to the standard font size setting you'll find an "extended setting" button. When you click it, you'll see (among others) a "minimum font size" - 10 px in Firefox.

So no matter what you do, as long as you don't change that setting, any text that is calculated to be less than 10px will be displayed at 10px...

I suppose the other browsers will have similar settings.

Comment: wow, i did not know that. Well, my Firefox is set to minimum "none" so that explains why it works. Tried to change it to 10, and it confirms what you say. Issue remians though, it works if I set the html tags font-size to a px based value instead of percentage.

Comment: you CAN use rem for bigger font sizes, but you must not expect that users will ever see fonts smaller than 10px on Firefox, 6 px on Chrome or whatever the default settings are, because most users will never change that.

Comment: Im going to accept your answer as its very close, but I can still get it to work if I set the font-size on the html tag in pixels, not percentage. Im not trying to set actual text to 1 or 2 pixels, but rather REM based width of a couple of DIV tags border. Anyhow, thank you @Johannes !

Comment: Look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdxwJw It's exactly your "not working" code - the only difference is that I set the html font-size to 500%. And you see that it works. So both the percentage and `rem` DO work in your example - it's just that minimum font-size setting of the browser that prevents it in smaller sizes.

Comment: Agreed. The problem was i couldn't get it further down than 6px. It seem Im allowed to have a DIVs font-size set to 4px and then set a child elements border to 1em so all good....i hope :)