# REM font size not adjusting below arbitrary threshold

Tags: css, blink

In Safari 12.0.2 and Chrome 71.0.3578.98 on Mac Mojave 10.14.2, when setting the `font-size` using `rem` units, the actual size won't go below `9px`.

See this example:

https://codepen.io/stephenjwatkins/pen/OrbGxL

[image: Rendered font size]

My browser's font size is set to the default (`16px`) with a minimum font size set to `6px`:

[image: Browser font settings]

Setting `text-size-adjust` to `none` doesn't affect the problem. Firefox renders the size correctly.

The only thing that I've found to fix the problem is setting `font-size: 0;` to a parent element. For instance, if you add `font-size: 0;` to `.container`, the correct font size is rendered.

Does anyone know why it's not honoring the `rem` size below a certain threshold?

Comment: When you add the vendor prefix of `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none` still no love?

Comment: Still no love with the vendor prefixed `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`.

Comment: this is a known feature, I will try to find the duplicate question

Comment: Ok @Temani Afif. Let me know.

Comment: not able to find it :/ will try again later

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302069/disable-chrome-minimum-font-size-10px but I can't close vote due to the bounty.

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578321/decimal-rem-based-font-size-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Aside from curiosity about browser quirks, is there a reason you want text smaller than 9px? I'd imagine the restriction is there as a feature to prevent text becoming illegible, because anything smaller isn't readable in a practical way. If you do need it for some reason, seems like using javascript to set `px` values is your only recourse.

Comment: Use some hacks like @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { .text {font-size: 6px;} } see more at http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302069/disable-chrome-minimum-font-size-10px. The minimum font size on the browser is set to `6px`, but it isn't being honored with `rem` units. For instance, I can set the font size to `6px` if I use `px` explicitly, but not lower than `6px`, as expected. This is a different problem.

Comment: Great! This response deserves more...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Chrome and its Blink rendering engine seem to have some non-obvious font-scaling rules. I'm unaware of any official comprehensive documentation, so let's go to the source.

*(Note that I'm not an expert on Chromium internals generally or Blink renderer particularly. I've just been tracing through the source code and speculating on the most probable answers to the questions as posed.)*

It seems to me that the engine calls upon [the `FontBuilder` class](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/94ccfef1071cee24bbe7125d79704a504c41106a/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/resolver/FontBuilder.cpp) during a redraw. This class has various dispatch methods that pass the DOM, zoom, and other relevant factors into what appears to be the crucial method: [`FontSize :: getComputedSizeFromSpecifiedSize`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/94ccfef1071cee24bbe7125d79704a504c41106a/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/FontSize.cpp). In that method, we see some juicy comments that address the points you've raised:

**1. Why does setting `font-size: 0;` to a parent element fix it?**

```
  // Text with a 0px font size should not be visible and therefore needs to be
  // exempt from minimum font size rules. Acid3 relies on this for pixel-perfect
  // rendering. This is also compatible with other browsers that have minimum
  // font size settings (e.g. Firefox).
```

**2. Why is it not honoring the rem size below a certain threshold?**

```
  // We support two types of minimum font size. The first is a hard override
  // that applies to all fonts. This is "minSize." The second type of minimum
  // font size is a "smart minimum" that is applied only when the Web page can't
  // know what size it really asked for, e.g., when it uses logical sizes like
  // "small" or expresses the font-size as a percentage of the user's default
  // font setting.

  // With the smart minimum, we never want to get smaller than the minimum font
  // size to keep fonts readable. However we always allow the page to set an
  // explicit pixel size that is smaller, since sites will mis-render otherwise
  // (e.g., http://www.gamespot.com with a 9px minimum).
```

**3. For the curious, what are these minimum values when given relative units (eg `x-small`)?**

```
// Strict mode table matches MacIE and Mozilla's settings exactly.
static const int strictFontSizeTable[fontSizeTableMax - fontSizeTableMin +
                                     1][totalKeywords] = {
    {9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 14, 18, 27},    {9, 9, 9, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30},
    {9, 9, 10, 11, 13, 17, 22, 33},  {9, 9, 10, 12, 14, 18, 24, 36},
    {9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 20, 26, 39},  // fixed font default (13)
    {9, 10, 12, 14, 17, 21, 28, 42}, {9, 10, 13, 15, 18, 23, 30, 45},
    {9, 10, 13, 16, 18, 24, 32, 48}  // proportional font default (16)
};
// HTML       1      2      3      4      5      6      7
// CSS  xxs   xs     s      m      l     xl     xxl
//                          |
//                      user pref
```

Interestingly, and a bit of an aside, the `FontBuilder` class dispatches to [TextAutosizer :: computeAutosizedFontSize](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/94ccfef1071cee24bbe7125d79704a504c41106a/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/layout/TextAutosizer.cpp) to scale the font size. This method uses hard coded values and a variable scaling factor:

```
  // Somewhat arbitrary "pleasant" font size.
  const float pleasantSize = 16;
  // Multiply fonts that the page author has specified to be larger than
  // pleasantSize by less and less, until huge fonts are not increased at all.
  // For specifiedSize between 0 and pleasantSize we directly apply the
  // multiplier; hence for specifiedSize == pleasantSize, computedSize will be
  // multiplier * pleasantSize. For greater specifiedSizes we want to
  // gradually fade out the multiplier, so for every 1px increase in
  // specifiedSize beyond pleasantSize we will only increase computedSize
  // by gradientAfterPleasantSize px until we meet the
  // computedSize = specifiedSize line, after which we stay on that line (so
  // then every 1px increase in specifiedSize increases computedSize by 1px).
  const float gradientAfterPleasantSize = 0.5;
```

From these facts, we see there are a good number of hard-coded pixel values, with `9` and `16` being commonly sprinkled about the relevant code. These hard-codes, the presence of several rules to scale the font down to a limit, with the ability to override using font-size all seem to match the observations and suggest it's behaving as intended -- if not necessarily intuitively.

---

Also, I've found that the most recent comment posted in [Chrome bug #319623](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319623#c54) very much resembles your report.

> Possibly related: when using relative units on the html tag, rem-based values defined elsewhere will have a lower bound of 9px.
>
> See CodePen: http://codepen.io/larrybotha/pen/wKYYXE
>
> Workaround: absolute unit on html, em unit on body. rems everywhere else.

It may be prudent to watch that bug for further developments, though maybe not with breath held. The last update was in 2015.

Comment: Good research and write-up. While I can't say that I fully grok Blink's logic, based on the problem and the code you shared here, I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Glad it helped, @StephenWatkins. I hope this analysis is at least in the ball-park, but I'd love a Chrome expert to phone in: this all seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: The workaround works only for font sizes on text. Unfortunately not if you are using rem on containers like divs for width/height ...

Comment: Earlier this year, in Chrome 73, there were issues that arose relative to min font size and rem units.  As a result, Chrome now allows a min font size of zero, and they changed the settings UI too.  But if you set your min font-size to non-zero, it can scale your rem units to be huge.  The UI jumps from zero to 6px as the available min sizes, nothing in between.
I too would love to see a Chrome expert explain this in further detail.

Comment: Another hack that works for me in safari (for both text as well as for sizes):
Set the font-size to e.g. `max(6px, 37.5%)` on the root element for a root font size of 6px.